# Adding Authorization or Headers with Cro::WebSocket::Client?

Tags: websocket, raku, cro

I'm using [Cro HTTP Authentication/Authorization/Sessions](https://cro.services/docs/http-auth-and-sessions) very successfully with HTTP routes.

Then I added a route that creates a `web-socket` using [`Cro::HTTP::Router::WebSocket`](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-router-websocket), and I can connect to it with [`Cro::WebSocket::Client`](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-websocket-client) and everything works fine.

Now I want to control access to the websocket, so I add a `Cro::HTTP::Auth` parameter.  Works great.  Now the the client gets a `401 Unauthorized` as expected.

Next step, how do I open the door?

With `Cro::HTTP::Client`, I can pass in an `Authorization` header, or even pass in the `auth` option.  How do I do that with `Cro::WebSocket::Client`?

I'm very new to WebSocket, so I don't even know if this is the right way to do things like this, but it seems like the `Cro::WebSocket::Client` `connect` method should take a `headers` named option that gets extra headers that get passed along.

Comment: I'd advise opening an issue in https://github.com/croservices/cro-websocket about this. The Cro team are pretty quick to respond. A cursory glance over the code doesn't look like Authorization headers on the initial connection are currently possible.

Comment: Raised an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/croservices/cro-websocket/issues/16

Comment: I didn't realize -- it looks like there is already a patch to do this: https://github.com/croservices/cro-websocket/pull/3

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned [patch](https://github.com/croservices/cro-websocket/pull/3) from titsuki was merged by Jonathan Worthington with commit [2593e21](https://github.com/croservices/cro-websocket/commit/2593e216b8249d22825ccc13d37566966066da35) on Oct 14, 2018